# Setting a requirement to go to the next screen app

Tags: powerapps

The first screen of my app contains a text input where the user has to enter an email address to continue.

I would like to set it as a mandatory field where "@" would be the character to recognize (a period "." would even make it more accurate).

At the moment, I am using the one below that will not let the user go to the next screen unless something is typed in the text input (anything, not necessarily an email address as I can't figure out the code for it).

```
If( IsBlank(TextInput1_4.Text) , Notify("Please enter your email address to continue!", NotificationType.Error) , Navigate('Main Screen',ScreenTransition.Cover) )
```

What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsMatch(TextInput1.Text, Match.Email)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-ismatch

Email is included on the Predefined Patterns.

Comment: It works by itself but how do I keep the notification and the navigate part?

Comment: @LioDjo you can add it as another condition and use && logical operator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/operators